# Where is the _images foler located?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server

I am trying to swap out an image on our server that has our old company logo. Someone else had put it in this location but I cannot seem to locate where it would be on the server file system or in any of the libraries. Any thoughts on how to locate this image?

Here is the URL:

`http://www.mydomain.com/_images/admin_logo.gif`

I feel like I am overlooking something really simple here....

Comment: Have you checked in the images folder within /_layouts/sitemanger.aspx ?

Comment: This doesn't appear to exist

Answer (score 1):

That should translate to `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\template\images` on the server. If they added it there manually, make sure it is added to all web servers in the farm. If it was deployed via feature, update and upgrade the feature.

Comment: Unfortunately I looked there and it doesn't appear there...

Comment: Well that's where the /_images directory maps to on the server and is the same location according to Visual Studio. You made sure to check a web server in your farm?

Comment: The images in that directory are visible via: http://ww2.mydomain.com/_layouts/Images/ ... not the URL mentioned above in my post.